# Why is this self-promoting answer not spam?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574527/3714134) for being obvious spam. It's clearly a marketing ploy of sorts, and the user has not had any other activity on the network.

Regardless, my flag as "non-disclosed self promotion" was declined. May I ask why?

Comment: How is it clearly marketing and not someone who just really likes StarUML, what link is there between the user and the product?

Comment: I guess the moderator chose to believe the author's introductory paragraph in which they refer to StarUML as one of the UML tools they explored?

Comment: Because no normal user can delete a highly upvoted post with just a single vote.  It is so over-the-top spammy that it got hilarious, why nobody has cast even a single downvote on it is hard to guess.  You can be the first.

Comment: It's an answer from 2011, I guess the rules have been different back then. It's not clearly spam and the user doesn't have an obvious connection to the star uml development. Especially: Why self promotion? I don't see the **self** unless you know that the author works for the company

Comment: @BDL: I think the self-promotion rules have largely been unchanged from that time.

Comment: In my experience, there is a big gray area between spam and self promotion (even if non-disclosed).  Because the SPAM flag carries a 100 rep penalty, mods seem to be much more cautious about accepting those flags.  However in this case, the user posted exactly 2 answers, both about the same product, both very spammy, and hasn't logged in since Jan 2011, I would think they made an error since the only purpose of that account seems to be promoting a specific product.  The upvotes on that answer may have also been something to do with it since it seemingly has helped people.

Comment: Well, the entire (pointless) question is gone now. Good job meta :)

Comment: the question itself was bad, and attracted spam & self promotion. The moderator didn't want to count that a spam, it was mere _provocation_ by question asker :)

Comment: Screenshot for non-10k users?

Comment: All of the "marked as duplicate" links do not answer my question. The answers to those questions are "flag it and it will be taken care of". **I flagged it and nothing happened.** **It took this question on meta.SO to get it removed.** @CodyGray